# Codeigniter multiple URL's while running form_validation->run()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `register_page.php` file in the views folder which is just a register form. When you click the register button, and say the password doesn't match, it should that the password doesn't match after clicking the submit button. However, after you type the password and it still doesn't match, it doesn't do anything, it just duplicates the url.

For example
URL when the password doesn't match: `http://localhost/dayone/user/register_user`
URL when when the password still doesn't match: `http://localhost/dayone/user/user/register_user`
At this point, the form is empty, all the values are removed and when you press enter without filling anything in, it doesn't show any error, but the URL says: `http://localhost/dayone/user/user/register_user`

What's causing this?

My `user.php` controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('register_page'); 
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }



    public function register_user () {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //rules to become a registered user

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|matches[password_conf]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        //user didn't validate, send back to login form and show errors

        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('register_page'); 
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');

        } else {
        //successful registration
        $this->load->view('login'); 
        }

    }
}
```

My `resister_page.php` (with the register form):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <div id="container" class="page">

        <div>
            <section class="container">
                <h2 class="block-title block-title--bottom">Login</h2>

                <div class="login">

                <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="alert-market">'); ?>

                 <form class="contact" id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="user/register_user">
                  <!--- FIRST NAME --->
                <input class="contact__field" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                    <!--- LAST NAME --->
                <input class="contact__field" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                 <!--- EMAIL --->
                <input class="contact__field" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">


                <!--- PASSWORD --->        
              <input class="contact__field" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <!--- CONFIRM PASSWORD --->   
              <input class="contact__field" name="password_conf" id="password_conf" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">

                        <a class="login__callback" href="#">Forgot password?</a>            
                        <input class="btn btn--decorated btn-warning login__btn"  value = "Login" name="submit" type="submit">
               <?php echo form_close(); ?>

                </div>
            </section><!-- end container -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- /#page -->

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Why bother to use `echo form_close()` when you're not using `echo form_open()`?  IMO, use `form_open()` so that the form is properly created including the hidden CSRF fields.  Typically in CodeIgniter, you cannot submit a form if you're not including the correct value of the CSRF token within the form data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Php/codeigniter. But how would I replace my code and implement the `form_open()`?

Comment: Start here:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Use `echo base_url('user/register_user')` or `form_open('user/register_user')` in form action.
Don't forget to load url helper before use.

Comment: also use matches on `password_conf` field to match with password

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this one:

```
<form class="contact" id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="user/register_user">
```

You can use this one:

```
<?php echo form_open('user/register_user');?>
```

Which is also equal to this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://localhost/dayone/user/register_user"/>
```

Assuming that your base_url in your config.php is equal to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dayone/';
```

I suggest you invest time in reading more about CodeIgniter's User Guide [here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide)

**EDIT:**

Do not forget to load your form and url helpers too. You can load them in autoload.php in application/config

```
$autoload['helper'] = array("url","form");
```

Or

Make a function __contruct() and load your helpers and models there.

Example:

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('sample_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
```

> Constructors are useful if you need to set some default values, or run
>    a default process when your class is instantiated. Constructors can't
>    return a value, but they can do some default work.
>
> --From [CodeIgniter - Controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) under Class Constructors

Answer (score 0):

First use form helper to form open

```
<?php echo form_open('user/register_user');?>
```

Then change your match password rules like(match confirm password to password):-

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|matches[password]|xss_clean');
```

Then your else part should be a redirect not load a view again like

```
else {
  // success register
  redirect('login');
}
```